# How to avoid the repeated code in java?

Tags: java

I'm just beginner in programming.
uf is a union-find class with the method union which connects the roots of two node.
This piece of code is responsible for opening a site of a grid and union the site with its neighbor if any of neighbor is opened. And if one of its neighbors is full, then fill all nodes that connected with the site.
This is the actual code:

```
        if(i == 1){
            uf.union(len*len, xyTo1D(i,j));
            if(existAndOpen(i+1,j)){
                uf2.union(xyTo1D(i+1,j), xyTo1D(i,j));
                uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i+1,j));
            }
            if(existAndOpen(i-1,j)){
                uf2.union(xyTo1D(i-1,j), xyTo1D(i,j));
                uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i-1,j));
            }
            if(existAndOpen(i,j-1)){
                uf2.union(xyTo1D(i,j-1), xyTo1D(i,j));
                uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j-1));
            }
            if(!(j == len && i == len)){
                if(existAndOpen(i,j+1)){
                    uf2.union(xyTo1D(i,j+1), xyTo1D(i,j));
                    uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j+1));
                }
            }
        }
        else{
        if(existAndFull(i+1,j)){
            uf2.union(xyTo1D(i+1,j), xyTo1D(i,j));
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i+1,j));
        }
        if(existAndFull(i-1,j)){
            uf2.union(xyTo1D(i-1,j), xyTo1D(i,j));
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i-1,j));
        }
        if(existAndFull(i,j-1)){
            uf2.union(xyTo1D(i,j-1), xyTo1D(i,j));
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j-1));
        }
        if(!(j== len && i == len)){
            if(existAndFull(i,j+1)){
                uf2.union(xyTo1D(i,j+1), xyTo1D(i,j));
                uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j+1));
            }
        }
        if(existAndOpen(i+1,j)){
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i+1,j));
        }
        if(existAndOpen(i-1,j)){
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i-1,j));
        }
        if(existAndOpen(i,j-1)){
            uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j-1));
        }
        if(!(j== len && i == len)){
            if(existAndOpen(i,j+1)){
                uf.union(xyTo1D(i,j), xyTo1D(i,j+1));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

How can I simplify the code?

Comment: Why don't you share your ideas first? It looks like you're dumping your homework.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to understand your issue. Right now, it appears that you don't need that first if-else statement at all. Please visit the [ask] page and [edit] your question.

Comment: @Spencer4134: I would not mind more details, but the `if` specifies if `f1` is used in tests, or `f2` is.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Amadan Oh I see. Missed that part.

Comment: google the Strategy pattern.  That appears to be what you want.  Another option is Visitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
boolean f1(int a, int b) { }
boolean f2(int a, int b) { }
void A(int a, int b) { }

void testAndA(BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> p, int a, int b) {
    if (p.test(a, b))
        A(a, b);
}
```

and

```
    if(x == 1){
        testAndA(this::f1, x + 1, y);
        testAndA(this::f1, x, y + 1);
    } else {
        testAndA(this::f2, x + 1, y);
        testAndA(this::f2, x, y + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Could also make `testAllAndA` to do both `testAndA`, as they are same in each branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a loop to loop through all of the different values that could be passed to f1(), such as something like:

```
for (int deltax = -1; deltax <= 1; deltax++) {
    for (int deltay = -1; deltay <= 1; deltay++) {
        if (f1(x + deltax, y + deltay)) {
            A(x + deltax, y + deltay);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course change the start and end values of deltax and deltay depending on which conditions you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

You say there are "more if statements in each block." Reading between the lines, I  assume that means you need to make more calls to `f1`/`f2` and `A`, but with different `x` and `y` offsets.

Here is a program that shows a way to refactor the code to avoid coding repetition. Its main features are:

- It uses object orientation to abstract the inner `if` blocks.
- It uses an `offsets` array to represent the `x`/`y` offsets for each inner `if` block.
- The `doIt()` method uses a loop to invoke the inner `if` blocks.

  ```
  public class Main {

      static interface F {
        void f(int i, int j);
      }

      static class F1Caller implements F {
        public void f(int a, int b) {
          if (f1(a, b)) {
            A(a, b);
          }
        }
      }

      static class F2Caller implements F {
        public void f(int a, int b) {
          if (f2(a, b)) {
            A(a, b);
          }
        }
      }

      static boolean f1(int a, int b) { System.out.print("  f1. "); return true; }
      static boolean f2(int a, int b) { System.out.print("  f2. "); return true; }
      static void A(int a, int b) { System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b); }

      static F1Caller f1Caller = new F1Caller();
      static F2Caller f2Caller = new F2Caller();

      // x and y offsets for each call to f1/f2.
      // Add more offset rows, as needed.
      static int offsets[][] = {
          {1,  0},
          {0, -1}
      };

      static void doIt(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);

        F f = (x == 1) ? f1Caller : f2Caller;
        for (int k = 0; k < offsets.length; k++) {
            f.f(x + offsets[k][0], y + offsets[k][1]);
        }
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) {
          doIt(0, 0);
          doIt(1, 0);
      }
  }
  ```

The output of the above program is:

```
x: 0, y: 0
  f2. a: 1, b: 0
  f2. a: 0, b: -1
x: 1, y: 0
  f1. a: 2, b: 0
  f1. a: 1, b: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the function together.

Using a switch.

```
public static boolean func(int a, int b, int fun)
{
     boolean output = false;
     switch(fun)
     {
     case 1:
         //do stuff
         output = true;
         break;
     case 2:
         //do stuff
         output = true;
         break;
     default:
         //unknown function handling
        output = false;
     }
     return output;
}
```

Integrate it with a for-loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     int i;
     //Change this to whatever you want or set it to a argument.
     int repeat = 2;
     for(i = 1; i <= repeat; i++)
     {
          func(a, b, i);
     }
}
```